# Machine Learning / Tensorflow : Model ends up stagnating to a certain accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

I'm currently trying to apply neural network algorithm to binary options, but I encounter some issues.

I chose to use a feed-forward multi layer neural net and I'm using tensorflow.

My data set is made like so :
- Each file contains roughly 80 000 input and output vectors and represents one month of data.
- Each input vector is made of n values of the currencies pair I want to study each m seconds/minutes before a reference date.
- The values are rescaled between 0 and 1, the min value of the input vector will be rescaled to 0 and the max value to 1.
- I have 47 of those files, so an epoch contains roughly 80 000 * 47 = 3 760 000 examples.

For almost all of my tries I used a batch size of 5000 and a learning rate of 0.0001 and I varied the number of hidden layers from 2 to 15.

Here are some of my results on the validation set, 1/3rd of the data set (a step on tensorboard graphs corresponds to one data file, or 1/47th of an epoch) :

[Hidden layers : 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNZ4c.png)
[Hidden layers : 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7PCr.png)

As you may notice, accuracy grows correctly then starts to stagnate at around 54%.

Do you guys have any idea of what I can do to avoid that ? I tried to decrease the learning rate when it starts to stagnate but it didn't work. Do I have to increase the number of hidden layers ? But in this case, learning could take a while. Or do I have to format my data another way ? Like trying to modify the time between 2 values ? Or to have a bigger input layer ?

Thanks to you all !

Comment: Why are you sure that the data you have really allows predictions with accuracy >54%? I'm no expert, but I think that predicting stocks based solely on their historical price won't yield anything significantly better than random.

Comment: You need to give more information about your data, your goal and especially how you set up your network. Please also post your code so that others can help your. And @yeputons is right: Depending on your data and use case it can very well be that your data has not causality towards the outcome that you wish to predict.

Comment: How is your training accuracy compared to validation accuracy?. Just to understand if its a case of `over-fitting`. Share their relative `accuracies` or `losses`